# SSRS Group totals report - multiple groups on the same row

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I’ve got question on grouping in SSRS that sounds pretty simple, but I can’t figure it out due to SSRS limitation on how you can move fields around in SSRS grouped reports. Please click on the below link for the suggested report layout. The data is grouped by all 3 fields – Employee/Order Type/Status. However, Order Type & Status fields should be displayed on one row, and SSRS doesn’t allow me to do that. I've done similar things in Crystal. Is it doable at all in SSRS?
[**PLEASE CLICK THIS LINK TO SEE THE PROPOSED REPORT LAYOUT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9YHq.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your rdl in design mode so that we can see how the groupings and tablix are setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was able to implement it using a free form report (List), subsequently adding a group to a list, then adding Employee Name and table with the rest of the fields. Subtotals were added within the list using expression and totals where adding using Add Total command of the Group

Answer (score 0):

Just give you a trick way to do that. 
1.In your original query, add `Group by Employee, OrderType, Status`. 
2.In SSRS, parse the query, then go to row group in the bottom, click the triangle drop down button of details group, `Add Parent group` for `Employee`
3. After step 2, it will generate a extra column for `Parent group`, then delete the `Employee` detail column and keep the parent `Employee` column

Update:
if you want to show the result like what you paste, `add group header` for parent group, then go to the header cell, set the value equal to `employee` field in the expression.

Comment: Hello LONG, it just doesn't work for me. I've added Group by to SELECT and also added all 3 groups  in SSRS report. But for some reason I'm getting all employees first, then all orders and so on. Not to mention, I can't get exactly same layout (Orders under Employee name, etc.). Also, I can't get count function working as group region is being defined by SSRS and I can't change it to fit my totals. It was so easy with Crystal, SSRS just killing me:)

Comment: would you mind copying what you see from the preview here?

Comment: Actually, I was able to implement it using a free form report (List), subsequently adding a group to a list, then adding Employee Name and table with the rest of the fields. Subtotals were added within the list using expression and totals where adding using Add Total command of the Group.